# function confirm() should trigger only after valid form submission not on page refresh

Tags: php, forms

I have `function confirm()` that should send a pop up confirmation to user when he successfully submits a contact form. It seems to work fine but if the user presses the page refresh in browser the function is triggered again and if I navigate back to the page from a linked page the `confirm()` function is triggered again.

I don't understand why because prior to `confirm()` function I reset two variables which should prevent the function being called.

```
<?PHP

/* Set e-mail recipient */
$myemail  = "bob@arnold.com";

/* Introduce the email message */
$themessage = "";

$nameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $commentErr = "";
$name = $email = $subject = $comment = "";


$nosubmit = 0;  //variable to check whether form data valid
$nosubmit_two = 0; //variable to check whether form data valid

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}

function confirm() {

echo "<script>";
echo "window.confirm('Thank you for your message. You should get an 
email confirmation.  I will reply to you in full as soon as I can. Have 
a nice day!')";
echo "</script>";

}





if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {




$name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);

// check if name only contains letters and whitespace
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {

$nameErr = "* Only letters and white space allowed";


}

else $nosubmit = 1;



$email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);

// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

$emailErr = "* Invalid email format"; 


}

else $nosubmit_two = 1;



$subject = test_input($_POST["Subject"]);


$comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);

if ($nosubmit == "1" && $nosubmit_two == "1") {


$themessage = "Message From:".$name."on the matter 
of:".$subject."Message reads:".$comment;
mail($myemail, $subject, $themessage);
$name = $email = $subject = $comment = "";
$nosubmit = 0;
$nosubmit_two = 0;
confirm(); // write function to alert user that email has been sent;

}


} // closes main if statement

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables you reset, are reset for that request only. They are automatically cleared by PHP when the page is served.
When the user presses the refresh button, the browser sends another POST request with the exact same information as the last time it sent data. it performs the exact same request as before.

To solve this, you can redirect the user to a certain page using php `header`, or you can store somewhere that the mail already has been sent (e.g. in a file, a database etc). The easiest method is to user `$_SESSION`

You first have to start the session `session_start()` somewhere at the top of your code, before any output is generated. Than you set e.g. `$_SESSION['mailHasSent'] = true` when the mail is sent, and you validate that this session variable is set or not before sending another mail.

The variables you store in $_SESSION remain over multiple page refreshes. More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. I will give that a try :)